Twitter API v2 geo place returning error 403
I'm trying to make a tweet search using keywords and a bounding box so I can get what people from a certain part of the world are tweeting about. But my query is not working.
This is the endpoint I'm using, I curling from R, but any help is welcomed:
curl --request GET 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?
'query=(<WORD1>%20OR%20<WORD2>%20OR%20<WORD3>)%20lang:es&expansions=geo.place_id&place.fields="geo"{"type":"Feature","bbox":[-100.3509,25.7045,-100.2675,25.666],"properties":{}}

And in R:
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
headers <- c(`Authorization` = sprintf('Bearer %s', bearer_token))
bbox <- c(-100.35094926882688,25.70447111708052,-100.26752438010853,25.665950026981893 )
keywords <- c("(<WORD1> OR <WORD2> OR <WORD3>)")
keywords <- paste0(keywords," lang:es")
endpoint <- "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent"
query <- paste(URLencode(keywords),
  sep=""
)
geo_json <- list(
  type = "Feature",
  bbox = bbox,
  properties = NULL
)
geo_json_str <- toJSON(geo_json, auto_unbox = TRUE)
geo_code <- paste("geo.place_id&",
                  "place.fields=",
                  '"geo": ',geo_json_str,sep = "")

response <- GET(
  url = endpoint,
  add_headers(.headers = headers),
  query = list(query = query,
               expansions=geo_code)
)

# Check the status of the response
if (status_code(response) != 200) {
  stop("Failed to fetch tweets: ", status_code(response))
}


I think you need to pay to run API queries like this now.
